# How to fix MethodNotAllowedHttpException error in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-5

I added a CRUD interface for my user's table, and instead of a delete button, I used a block button. Which blocks a user (sets bloque field in the database from 0 to 1). I added a new function in my controller called block which is supposed to do the job yet I get a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` error every time I click the blocking button.

**UserController**

```php
public function block($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->bloque = 1;
    $user->save();

    return redirect('/users')->with('success', 'Utilisateur bloqué');
}
```

**The blocking HTML fragment**

```
<form action="{{ route('users.block', $user->id)}}" method="get">
@csrf
    <!--  @method('DELETE')-->
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Bloquer</button>
</form>
```

**Routes**

```php
Route::get('/block', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@block',
    'as' => 'users.block'
]);
```

Comment: Do you get the same error if you change it to a `POST` route instead? Also do you have any other routes with the same uri?

Comment: I would also try adding the {id} to your route like so: `Route::get('/block/{id}', [])`

Comment: Hey Ian, it gave the same error when i changed it to POST, if you see the blocking form html fragment the method is GET, and i tried doing Route::get('/block/{id}', []) but i get a page not found error.

Comment: Does `php artisan route:list` show any conflicting routes? You really shouldn't be doing anything destructive with a `GET` call, incidentally.

Comment: I apologize for not including it (I hit enter too early), and the seeming obvious question, but did you still include the ['uses' => 'UserController@block', 'as' => 'users.block'] in the array? 

Also, Can you post the value of the action `<form action="">` attribute that renders in the HTML? 

Something else you can try, since this is a GET request, is type it into a browser window to test, do you receive an error if you do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is related to id value, It should be instantiated from $request object. Like:

```
public function block(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::find($request->id);
    $user->bloque = 1;
    $user->save();

    return redirect('/users')->with('success', 'Utilisateur bloqué');
}
```